# office 365 users, is the AD property 'division' mapped correctly in your tenancy?

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile-service

I need to use the AD property called Division but it looks not mapped (users using this property shows 0) while I have people in AD using the property.

Anyone?

Comment: There are a lot of properties not mapped by default, and some mapped with different names (can't find that blog in 2 minutes..) So you have to go into SharePoint configuration and set the required mapping yourself.

Comment: found: http://www.kouti.com/tables/userattributes.htm and http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.nl/2016/05/sharepoint-search-for-people-using.html that helped me

Comment: ok but what about 'division' specifically, if you have sharepoint online

Answer (score 0):

I don't see Division in my (SPO) People search code, I presume it is not mapped.

## Update

alas: [source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3168272/information-about-user-profile-synchronization-in-sharepoint-online)

> Q4.Why isn't it possible to map additional properties for AD Import to
> sync from Azure Active Directory to the User Profile Application?
>
> A4. AD Import is limited to a preconfigured set of properties to
> guarantee consistent performance of the timer job.

Your only option then is to move your Division info to another field

Comment: You can not map in SPO I'm afraid? Or has this changed recently? :)

Comment: You mean AD doesn't sync that field Division? (I had never heard of it, nor used it) In that case it might be easier to use other fields in the AD,

Comment: For SharePoint Online only the default user profile mappings are synchronized (they are listed here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147510.aspx). For syncing other properties from Azure AD to SP you'll need custom code (at least last time I had this requirement on my agenda)

Comment: The field division is among the AD fields not displayed in the tabs, you need to go to see the full list of attributes. This field cannot feed the sharepoint user profile, which is bad